# No operations defined in spec! asp .net core 3.1, swagger is not showing controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, swagger, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66683628/swagger-no-operation-define-in-spec-asp-net-core-3-1) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62524433/swagger-returning-no-operations-defined-in-spec) several links but not getting the answer.

this is my startup.cs file

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
            services.AddCommonService(Configuration);
            services.AddSecurityServiceRepositories();
            services.AddSwaggerService();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseSwaggerService();
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseAuthorization();
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
            //app.UseMvc();
        }
```

Adding service class, it adds the repositories

```
    namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    {
    public static class SecurityServiceRepositoryCollectionExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddSecurityServiceRepositories(this 
    IServiceCollection 
         services)
        {
            services.AddTransient<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
            return services;
        }
      }
    }
```

this is my swagger class file, it adds and uses the basic swagger service

```
    namespace Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
    {
    public static class SwaggerServiceExtension
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddSwaggerService(this IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
            {
                options.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo
                {
                    Title = "Sample API",
                    Version = "v1",
                    Description = "REST API for Sample "
                });
                options.AddSecurityDefinition("Bearer", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                {
                    Description = @"JWT Authorization header using the Bearer scheme. \r\n\r\n 
                      Enter 'Bearer' [space] and then your token in the text input below.
                      \r\n\r\nExample: 'Bearer 12345abcdef'",
                    Name = "Authorization",
                    In = ParameterLocation.Header,
                    Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Scheme = "Bearer"
                });
                options.AddSecurityRequirement(new OpenApiSecurityRequirement()
                {
                    {
                        new OpenApiSecurityScheme
                        {
                            Reference = new OpenApiReference
                            {
                                Type = ReferenceType.SecurityScheme,
                                Id = "Bearer"
                            },
                            Scheme = "oauth2",
                            Name = "Bearer",
                            In = ParameterLocation.Header
                        },
                        new List<string>()
                    }
                });
            });
            return services;
        }
        public static IApplicationBuilder UseSwaggerService(this IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseSwagger();
            app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
            {
                c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Sample  Api V1");
            });

            return app;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my controller, I have tried the both attribute

```
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class UserController : SecuredRepositoryController<IUserRepository>
    {
        public UserController(IUserRepository repository) : base(repository) { }

        [HttpPost("register-user")]
        // [Route("register-user")] I also tried this routing
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ProducesResponseType(typeof(User), 200)]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddNewUser([FromBody] User user)
        {
            try
            {
                var result = await this.Repository.RegisterUser(user);
                return Ok(result);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(500, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

This is coming on swagger UI instead of Controller, check the screenshot
[image]

Comment: I suspect it has something to do with the base class of your controller. Try inhering from the ControllerBase class ( you might need to comment out any code that uses the repository - but at least you would see if it appears in the swagger UI.

Comment: I tried that too, got the same issue, @NickGoloborodko

Comment: Try creating a basic controller `public class TestController: ControllerBase { [HttpGet("/test")] public ActionResult Index() { return Ok(); } }` and see if it shows up

Comment: I have already tried it @abdusco

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had to reference the project to the Host project which contains the Program

Comment: would be good to add a bit more details

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error when creating a new ASP.NET core web api project, but forgot to check "Use controllers (uncheck to use minimal APIs)" in Visual Studio.  Recreating the project with that box checked solved the issue for me.